# Is it grammatically correct to say: "Answer it"?

Tags: grammar

Is the sentence "Answer it" grammatically correct?
Would it be more correct to say "Answer that" or "Answer this"
*Ex: "My question is simple, answer it."*

Comment: **Grammatically**, _answer it_ and _answer that/this_ are identical. In some contexts their **meaning** can be different, and one or other may be **pragmatically** preferable.

Answer (score 3):

"Answer it." or "Answer it!" are both valid sentences on their own in the imperative mood. It is asking for a response to something (e.g. a question, a ringing phone, a doorbell, etc.)

"Answer this" usually appears before a question. That question would be a part of the same sentence after a colon. The question often needs no response. It simply wants the listener/reader to think about the question.

> Answer this: why would they learn how to speak English at a bad school?

"Answer this!" is also a valid sentence. There is something happening *close by* and the speaker/writer wants the listener/reader to respond to it immediately.

> (A doorbell rings. The speaker says to someone while pointing at the door in front of them) Answer this!

"Answer that!" is another valid sentence. There is something happening *relatively far away* and the speaker/writer wants the listener/reader to respond to it.

> (A phone rings. The speaker says to someone while pointing at the phone across the room) Answer that!

"Answer that." or "Answer that!" would also appear after a question that was presented before. This short sentence urges the listener/reader to respond to the question.

> "Why would they learn how to speak English at a bad school? Answer that!"

Answer (score -1):

All of those are correct, albeit applicable in different contexts. I'll give some examples presently.

1. $:What would you if asked a question on which quarks are coloured?
   #:I would answer it.
   Note that the other two possibilities don't fit here.
2. $:Do you have any tasks for me?
   #:Yes, answer this call (hands over a cellphone).
   $:(After finishing the call) Anything else I can do?
   #:Could you answer that question on the board (points to the blackboard)?

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question posed.

Comment: Thank you very much @codesPliff. If it is used in an imperative mood (?), would "answer it" still be correct? 
Ex: "My question is simple, answer it."

Comment: @amusebouche Yeah, that's a valid sentence.